# How to debug JaCoCo gradle-plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I use JaCoCo when develop android apps.

I think the function `excludes` of JaCoCo might have a bug.

So I want to debug JaCoCo gradle-plugin.

I tried to debug by jacoco.cli as below.

```
    $ git clone https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco.git
    $ cd jacoco
    $ mvn clean verify -DskipTests
    $ java -jar ./org.jacoco.cli/target/org.jacoco.cli-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT-nodeps.jar report ./testDebugUnitTest.exec --classfiles ../../github/att/android-app/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes --html "./jacoco-report" --name testReport --sourcefiles "../../github/att/android-app/app/src"
```

But jacoco.cli doesn’t have a excludes option…

- all cli options
  https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/046ba52e9fd1288cf121fd1013c9019d71946954/org.jacoco.cli/src/org/jacoco/cli/internal/commands/Report.java#L51-L73

I asked the JaCoCo project, but I was told to contact gradle project.
https://groups.google.com/g/jacoco/c/NEjyUtPX5eA/m/JWa7avf_AAAJ

How can I debug JaCoCo gradle-plugin?

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

Please tell me the way to debug JaCoCo gradle-plugin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You can basically debug any Gradle build and its plugins using the procedure described in the [Gradle Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/troubleshooting.html#sec:troubleshooting_build_logic).

It might not be a bug in the plugin though. Maybe you just didn't quite get the config right yet. In particular, you often need to configure both the test task and the report task. [For example](https://gitlab.com/barfuin/gradle-jacoco-log/-/blob/d5af79b9365ec7a735f98730e6168dc3bb2816b3/src/functionalTest/resources/setup08-aggregateReconfigured/module3-exclusions/build.gradle#L26-36),

```
// Exclude class Hello4 from Jacoco Coverage in this sub-project:

test {
    jacoco {
        excludes = ['Hello4']
    }
}
jacocoTestReport {
    classDirectories.setFrom(fileTree(dir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.first()).exclude(['**/Hello4*']))
    sourceDirectories.setFrom(fileTree(dir: sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.first()).exclude(['**/Hello4*']))
}
```

Comment: @burfuin Thank you for your answer! I want to set logs in Jacoco gradle-plugin and debug by printing the logs . Do you know the way to set logs in Jacoco gradle-plugin?

Comment: Well you might call Gradle with `--debug` to get more log output, but the jacoco plugin does not contain many log statements (or any at all), so it will not gain you much, I'm afraid.